# Can't factory reset my Galaxy S20

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I'm trying to factory reset a Galaxy S20 because I've forgotten to add MDM in the intial setup and as far as I know you can't add this later.

To do the factory reset I've done Settings > General Management > Reset > Factory data reset. Then tap Reset and Delete all. But it then asks me to confirm my Samsung Account which it somehow can't do, because I always get a loading icon which fails after some time. Then it asks me for the password of my Samsung Account and again goes into a loading icon which also just stops after some time. I don't get any error message.

There's also the option to send a confirmation e-mail, but this also leads to the loading screen but after some time I get a little pop-up telling me there is a network error. The screen here stays white and I need to use the back button to go the confirmation screen of my Samsung Account.

I do have internet access on my phone, because I can open websites with Chrome. I'm using my home Wlan Network to connect to the internet.

I didn't find any solution to this problem with Google, just the normal documentation from Samsung of how to factory reset a phone, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you removed all accounts shown in Settings -> Accounts (or wherever the accounts are listed on Samsung devices)?

Comment: No I didn't, I didn't know you need to do this before a factory reset. But it looks like I can't remove my Samsung Account?

Comment: You don't have to, but without any accounts left there should be no query for Samsung account data.

Comment: I've removed my other accounts, but I don't see how I can remove my Samsung account and it still asks me for it in the factory reset.

Comment: Your Samsung account should be present in the accounts list: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00062033/

Comment: Yes thanks it was a little more hidden with the Samsung account than with the others. Here I have the same problem with accessing the Samsung account site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that somehow my phone couldn't access the Samsung Account site over my home network. I've switched to a hotspot of my other phone, and now everything is working as it should. I was lead to this solution because I've seen other people having problems with accessing the Samsung Account site. Perhaps some providers have problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to factory reset your Samsung device, you must hold the Home, Power, and Volume Up button. It will then take you to the Samsung recovery mode. When there, use the volume keys to control the options and the home buttons to press. There should be an option called factory reset, press that and wait for it to delete all data from your phone. Then, click restart the phone. The phone should boot up normally and the setup will begin. I hope this solved your problem.

Regards.

Comment: after factory reset that still requires password of Samsung Account on initial setup - which for some reason did not confirm because of network issues. this answer is partially helpful, but will not solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

There is a sort of recovery mode called EDL, the new ODIN mode.
As you are using a samsung phone, download galaxy S20 firmware (you need to type somewhere the phone e.g. SM-G530FZ Galaxy Grand Prime phone code), and downlaod Odin.
Shut Down completely your phone.
Press volume down button until connect your phone to pc, and the phone should be recognized  by ODIN.
Else if it's not, Download some EDL Utility.

Comment: EDL mode is for qualcomm chipset only, this phone is Exynos chipset. EDL mode always existed on qualcomm devices, not to mix up with Odin/Download mode (which is a different mode). EDL mode requires device specific OEM signed factory loader (firehose programmer) which is not available for consumer

Comment: Ok, sorry becasue i don't know what CPU has every phone,

Comment: Anyways, thanks.